# Splitting one bulk email in to several

Tags: .net-2.0, bulk-email

We have a website and we just ran into a problem when trying to send 700 emails in one bulk. I'm thinking it's better to send 100 emails 7 times but which approach should I take?

- I could just use a for loop and send an email 7 times but is there any problems with this approach, e.g. if the amount of emails double?
- Threading, which I'm new to and would take more time.

Here's my code:

```
protected void btnClick_Send(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage();
     mailObj.Bcc.Add(txtReciever.Text.Trim());
     mailObj.ReplyToList.Add("our-reply-email@oursite.com");
     mailObj.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
     mailObj.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
     mailObj.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
     mailObj.Body += Environment.NewLine;
     mailObj.Body = txtContent.Text;
     mailObj.Body += Environment.NewLine;
     SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
     SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
}
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you on?

Comment: I'm on 2.0 at the moment, but I think I can upgrade to 4 if it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely one of those [embarrassingly parallel problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), which would gain great benefit from parallelism.

In .NET 4.0 you can have that code run in parallel by simply using the [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx) method.

Assuming that `messages` is a sequence of objects containing the `Receiver`, `Subject` and `Body` of the e-mails to send, this example uses the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to automatically send *as many of them as possible* out in parallel given the resources available on the machine:

```
Parallel.ForEach(messages, message =>
{
     MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage();
     mailObj.Bcc.Add(message.Receiver);
     mailObj.ReplyToList.Add("our-reply-email@oursite.com");
     mailObj.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
     mailObj.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
     mailObj.Subject = message.Subject;
     mailObj.Body += Environment.NewLine;
     mailObj.Body = message.Body;
     mailObj.Body += Environment.NewLine;
     SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
     SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
}
```

Of course, you can implement the same solution in .NET 2.0 as well, for example using the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx) method to manually schedule the e-mails to be sent out on different threads, but it would definitely require more effort.

Comment: What's the difference between this and the for loop? Asking because I don't know...

Comment: A conventional loop will process the items sequentially *one at a time*. A [parallel loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989744.aspx) will automatically break the list down into chunks and process them *at the same time*. The number and size of the chunks depend on the resources available on the machine, like the number of CPU cores.